# Console logging certain objects don't work when developing a Firefox extension using React

Tags: firefox-addon, reactjs, firefox-addon-sdk

Console logging certain objects, like `this.refs` or the `window` object results in a `TypeError: cyclic object value` error in the terminal.

My code is pretty basic: I'm trying to change the html on a web page (placing a react component in it).

Main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var { MatchPattern } = require("sdk/util/match-pattern");

// Create a page mod
// It will run a script whenever a ".org" URL is loaded
// The script replaces the page contents with a message
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: /.*wikipedia.org\/wiki\/.*/,
  contentScriptFile: [
        self.data.url("react-with-addons.js"),
        self.data.url("testing.js"),
    ],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    // contentStyleFile: self.data.url("style.css"),
});
```

testing.js:

```
var AppContainer = React.createClass({displayName: "AppContainer",

   componentDidMount: function() {
      console.log(this.refs.myRef);
      console.log(window);
   },

   render: function() {
      console.log('rendering');
      return (
         React.createElement("div", {ref: "myRef"})
         );

   }
});

React.render(React.createElement(AppContainer, null), document.getElementById('content'));
```

After running `cfx run`, the logs in the componentDidMount do not display anything in the browser console, and the `cyclic object value` displays (tried to log the window object to the console). Why is it having difficulties?

Comment: Objects logged are live. Meaning the latest value is shown when you look at it. To look at what it was at the time of logging do an `uneval` on it so log it like: `console.log('unevaled obj:', uneval(obj))` that will give you the values of obj at that time. There's a bugzilla topic open about it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754861

Comment: Just place a brake point or write `debugger;` in the code and you will be able to examine the variable's state when the execution stops there.